# R Caret Train Input values

Tags: r, function, r-caret

I want to make a list of input values for the caret train function to ignore. So far I can do it and it works, however, it has to be done withing the train function.

Example:

```
LabCa_R1_Fit <- train(LabCa ~ . -EV1 -kgpm -Fe ,...)
```

The **-EV1 -kgpm -Fe** is me removing the values, however, I want it in the form of:

```
list <- c(-EV1, -kgpm, -Fe)
LabCa_R1_Fit <- train (LabCa ~ . list, ...)
```

The problem is when I put the options to delete outside the train function they area treated as variables instead of options and I get the appropriate error. How do I create a list of the options I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also an undocumented feature that will allow you do use:

```
mod <- train(Species ~ ., data = iris, method = "lda", preProc = list(ignore = "Sepal.Width"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by doing the following:

```
# Outside
list <- LabCa ~ . -EV13

# Inside
LabCa_R1_Fit <- train( list , ... )
```